# Using a test certificate digitally sign a document in aspose.words

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature, x509certificate, aspose

I am trying to create a unit test that generates an empty test document similar to the one found in the Aspose Words example. I created  a test cert using makecert.exe with the following line in the VS Command Promp

```
makecert.exe -sv MyKey.pvk -n "CN=MY DIGITAL KEY" MyKey.cer
```

I then converted it to a .pvk file using the following line

```
pvk2pfx.exe -pvk MyKey.pvk -spc MyKey.cer -pfx MyPFX.pfx
```

After this was done I copied the .pfx file into my .net console app and set the copy parameter to copy always so that the file is copied to the bin directory when I test the app in debug.

My console app then contains the following lines of code which tries to write a digitally signed pdf.

```
static void Main()
{
string MyDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
// Create a simple document from scratch.
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
builder.Writeln("Test Signed PDF.");
// Load the certificate from disk.
// The other constructor overloads can be used to load certificates from different locations.
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(MyDir + "RpaKey.pfx", "");
Console.WriteLine("Loading certificate...");
// Pass the certificate and details to the save options class to sign with.
PdfSaveOptions options = new PdfSaveOptions();
options.DigitalSignatureDetails = new PdfDigitalSignatureDetails(
cert,
"Test Signing",
"Aspose Office",
DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine("Creating digital signature details...");
try
{
// Save the document as PDF with the digital signature set.
doc.Save(MyDir + "Document.Signed Out.pdf", options);
Console.WriteLine("File saved successfully.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine("File write failed.");
Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
if (ex.InnerException != null)
{
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
}
}
Console.ReadKey();
}
```

However I keep getting an "invalid algorith specified" error with no inner exception. Has any one run into this problem? Have I missed a step? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used Aspose myself but you should first ensure that your conversion from the PVK to the PFX format worked like you expected.

Change this:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(MyDir + "RpaKey.pfx", "");
Console.WriteLine("Loading certificate...");
```

to

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(MyDir + "RpaKey.pfx", "");
Console.WriteLine("Loading certificate... private key available ? {0}", cert.HasPrivateKey);
```

Note that it likely did success since there was no exception - but that will at least confirm the first part of your process is valid :-)

If this shows **true** then you should update your question to show the full stack trace from your exception, e.g.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

so we'll see if the error comes from Aspose or the BCL itself.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Poupou that full stack trace would help to understand where exactly the exception is generating and why. Moreover, if this problem persists at your end then you may also contact our support team via [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx) as well. We'll have to investigate this issue in detail and see if it is actually caused by Aspose.Words. And if so, we'll provide you the fix for that.

Moreover, as you're creating a very simple document, it looks like the issue is probably caused by the signature. Could you please try with some other signature file?

Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.